# Generating an SSL Key to work with node.js

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl

I'm working to setup a SSL via GoDaddy to use with my node.js server on AWS EC2. I've been unable to get it to work.

Here's what I've tried:

Intended for the domain: files.mysite.com

**On the server I run:**

```
$ openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout files.mysite.key -out files.mysite.csr

Common Name: files.mysite.com
password: left empty
```

I then get the CSR: vim files.mysite.csr

I copy and paste from:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
......... lots of stuff
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

There is an extra empty line at the end, which I leave and paste into the GoDaddy interface using rekey.

I then download the godaddy key which provides:

```
gd_bundle.crt
files.mysite.com.crt
```

Then in node I insert:

```
key: fs.readFileSync('server.key').toString(),
cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt').toString()
```

I'm not sure what server.key is or server.crt given that GoDaddy provides two crt files?
Can you help?

Comment: This question is also an answer. Your openssl command is appropriate to "generate a CSR for Node.js apps" Either that's REALLY obvious and I'm slow or it's not and there are likely a lot of people like me that need that info so I wish I could upvote this for both a question AND answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

GoDaddy uses an intermidiate certificate to sign your certificate. This has several advantages to both you and GoDaddy. But it takes a bit more work to get it to work (just a bit, mostly googling around).

In node.js you can install them like this:

```
require('https').createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('files.mysite.com.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('files.mysite.com.crt'),
    ca: [fs.readFileSync('gd_bundle.crt')] // <----- note this part
}, app).listen(443);
```

Comment: Why do you have [] around the ca but not the other fields?

Comment: @RachelDRoy: Read the documentation. `ca` accepts an array of certificates in case there is more than one chain. For example, if `gd_bundle` itself was signed by another certificate.

Comment: Eureka!  It works!  the `note this part` in the example was especially helpful with my GoDaddy SSL certificate.

Comment: Since you are trying to pass an array to `ca`, you should split properly

Answer (score 3):

You should use `.crt` and `.key` files at the creation of your http server instance. The following snippet will give you the idea :

```
require('https').createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/something.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/something.crt'),
}, app).listen(443);
```

If you have a passphrase for your key, you can pass it though as follows :

```
require('https').createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/something.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/something.crt'),
    passphrase: 'your_secret_passpahrase'
}, app).listen(443);
```