# Node.js, socket.io https connection

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, socket.io

Server side code:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8150);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){

});
```

Client side code:

```
var socketIO = io('*.*.*.*:8150');
socketIO.once('connect', function(){

});
```

On http it's worked on https in same page it not connected.
Searched many examples, but all example for express. I dont create any http server in node.js need only to socket.io work.

Comment: Did you change any of the code above when changing the HTML page to https?

Comment: No i dont change any code. It's original code work on http and dont work on https.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When running the client over HTTPS, socket.io is attempting to connect to your server over HTTPS as well. Currently your server is only accepting HTTP connections, the `listen(port)` function does not support HTTPS.

You'll need to create an HTTPS server and then attach socket.io to it, something like this.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('certs/privkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('certs/fullchain.pem')
};

var app = require('https').createServer(options);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
app.listen(8150);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

});
```

And if you need both HTTP and HTTPS, you can start two servers and attach socket.io to both.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('certs/privkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('certs/fullchain.pem')
};

var httpServer = require('http').createServer();
var httpsServer = require('https').createServer(options);
var ioServer = require('socket.io');

var io = new ioServer();
io.attach(httpServer);
io.attach(httpsServer);
httpServer.listen(8150);
httpsServer.listen(8151);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

});
```

Then on the client side you can determine which port to connect to based on whether the page was accessed over HTTP or HTTPS.

```
var port = location.protocol === 'https:' ? 8151 : 8150;
var socketIO = io('*.*.*.*:' + port);
socketIO.once('connect', function() {

});
```

Comment: I have 3 files.
server.key - (server private key) //
server.crt - (my server certificate) //
chsert.crt - (chained other certificates).

How i can generate privkey.pem and fullchain.pem.
I try rename files to .pem but get error

`Error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch`

Comment: How i can create fullchain.pem?

Comment: Those files should work as-is. Set `key:` to your `server.key` file, `cert:` to your `server.crt` file, and add a `ca:` property as an array containing your `chsert.crt` file. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13450299/2288513) answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use letsencrypt with Plesk for a valid SSL certificat.

```
options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/usr/local/psa/var/modules/letsencrypt/etc/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/usr/local/psa/var/modules/letsencrypt/etc/live/mydomain.com/cert.pem'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('/usr/local/psa/var/modules/letsencrypt/etc/live/mydomain.com/chain.pem'),
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    requestCert: true,
    agent: false
 }
```