# Can't connect socket.io node server to react frontend. "POST http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MoHNIJT 404 (Not Found)"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I have created a frontend in react and a backend in express nodejs, and I am using socket.io for the client and server to communicate.

When I load the react page I get the following error every second:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I have set the frontend to run on port 3000 and the server to run on port 3500. The failed connect requests are being sent to the address: 
http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MoHUt8D

Below is the setup for the node backend:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 
'https://www.localhost:3000');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, DELETE, PATCH, PUT');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  next();
});

const server = https.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

console.log('Server listening on port 3500.');
server.listen(3500);
```

And the client side connects as follows:

```
import openSocket from "socket.io-client";
const hostURL = "http://localhost:3500";
const socket = openSocket()
```

Any advice on how to stop the error and have the front and backend working with socket.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `http` library instead of the `https` one.

`server.listen(3500)` does not support https. If for some reason you do need to use it, you can reference [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47581486/11929924).

Also, on your client you need to tell the socket library the URL of the host, otherwise it will default to `window.location` as mentioned [here in the docs](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/) which seems to be your case as you mentioned the requests are directed towards `localhost:3000` and your server is on `localhost:3500` so change this

```
import openSocket from "socket.io-client";
const hostURL = "http://localhost:3500";
const socket = openSocket()
```

to this

```
import openSocket from "socket.io-client";
const hostURL = "http://localhost:3500";
const socket = openSocket(hostURL)
```